# How can get the selected option id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get the id of selected option from dropdown but i get the nill id when i create the project

```
def create


    developer_id = params[:developer_id]
    parameters = project_params.merge({ user_id: current_user.id, developer_id: developer_id })
    @project = Project.new(parameters)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
         format.html { redirect_to projects_path, flash: { success: 'Project added successfully ' } }
      else
         format.html { render :new }
      end

   end
end

def project_params
   params.require(:project).permit(:name, :user_id)
end
```

new.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for :project, :html => {:class=>"form-group"}, url: projects_path  do |f| %>

   Add task: <%=f.text_field :name, class:"form-control" %><br>
   <h2>Select Developer</h2>
   <%= f.select :developer_id, options_for_select(@users.collect  {|user|["#{user.name}","#{user.id}"]}) %><br>


   <%= f.submit "Add" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `developer_id` is nested under `project` just like the other params.

```
developer_id = params[:project][:developer_id]
```

or

```
developer_id = params.dig(:project, :developer_id)
```

When you are unsure where to find certain params or if they even exist then the easiest way is certainly to look into your applications log file. There you should see the incoming request and all the params and how they are nested.